# WCF Still get error with maximum message size when already increased it

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I've just researched many topic and can't figure out why and I still get this problem.
My config at server.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.Services.Service">
        <endpoint  behaviorConfiguration="LargeDataBehavior" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Services.UI.IService" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MyService.Services/Service/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding bypassProxyOnLocal="True" name="MyBinding" textEncoding="utf-8" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LargeDataBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

And then I run WCF Test Client.

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Inner Exception:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Sorry for my bad English.
Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error, it sounds like you need to increase the `maxReceivedMessageSize` attribute in the WCFTestClient config, not the service.

To do this, go the bottom of the left side of the WCFTestClient and right-click on the Config File node, and select "Edit with SvcConfigEditor".

[image]

In the window that pops up, select the binding you want to edit, and you can adjust all the values as needed in the right-hand pane.

[image]

Note that this will only persist for that WCFTestClient session; once you close it, you'll lose the settings and it will revert to the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like the configuration is not correct for the service because after applying the binding configuration at endpoint level it is still giving the same issue for max size.
Your binding configuration is correct but behavior configuration should be on service level not on end point level.

Add `behaviorConfiguration="newBehaviour"` behavior to service level node i.e. `'<services>'` tag and you can remove the behavior at endpoint tag as behavior is service level so specify your behavior configuration on service tag.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services name="MyService.Services.Service" behaviorConfiguration="newBehaviour" >
    <endpoint  address=""   binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Services.UI.IService" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding">
             <identity>
               <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
         </endpoint><endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MyService.Services/Service/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding bypassProxyOnLocal="True" name="MyBinding" textEncoding="utf-8" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None">
               <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="LargeDataBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
         </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="newBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
            <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It's not my problem guy. I did it and still same error. Thank for your advice.

Comment: Fine, it seems like you added maximum size setting to your client application from where you are consuming the WCF service, I think you have to add these setting to your WCF service too.